# Convert string date in useable panda format

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I Download Weather data from the Germany weather agency dwd.de and want to plot them (over 1300 data).

The Data contains two column: first the date in year+month+day+hour and for example the air temperature.

data example:

```
Date         TT_TU
2018112319   21.7
```

How can i convert the Date string into a useable format for python pandas to plot it with matplotlib?

For now i use the index to plot the data frame, but this is not the solution i want.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel('Table.xlsx')
plt.plot(df.index, df.TT_TU)
plt.show()
```

Actual python plot

[image: actual python plot]

Comment: `datetime` has `strptime` to parse time

Comment: see argument `format` in function [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pandas.to_datetime(..., format='%Y%m%d%H')`

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Date': ['2018112319'], 'TT_TU': [21.7]}  # columns

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y%m%d%H')

print(df)
```

Result

```
                 Date  TT_TU
0 2018-11-23 19:00:00   21.7
```

Doc [pandas.to_datetime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)